# cannot click on link Python Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am trying to add a confirmation link on selenium but selenium is not able to click on that link

its on yopmail with name janemartin90452

It doesn't click on the confirmation link Name "Activate Your Account"

```
emailconfirmationatyopmail = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mail > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > a')

emailconfirmationatyopmail.click()
```

Element is
Activate Your Account

Comment: I have tried xpath as well Same thing

Comment: <a name="CTA" bgcolor="#1dbf73" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); background-color: rgba(29, 191, 115, 1); display: inline-block; font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-size: 16px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 20px; border-radius: 3px; text-transform: none" href="http://www.fiverr.com/linker?activation_token=ngum4wbyW7BHVukGa6&amp;view=activation&amp;email_id=1ce74c84099e8ae6f40615d1e7d47c89&amp;email_name=activation_instructions">Activate Your Account</a>

Answer (score 0):

That selector is positional based and likely to break as other emails pour in and/or the website updates its UI. Also, a `.click()` *should* "bubble" up from the  to its parent `<button>` but we can target the button directly for interaction.

I checked out the inbox and was able to successfully find the parent `<button>` of the 'Activate Your Account' `<div>` using XPath.

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Activate Your New Account')]/parent::button
```

You can verify this by opening (F12) DevTools and doing a (Ctrl+F) search in the DOM tab.

Comment: Sir i am not quite Sure yet!! how will i impliment it?

Comment: I am quite new in selenium Kindly If you could tell me what should I do Exactly on that link if possible Thanks

Comment: driver.get("http://yopmail.com/")


emailatyopamil = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#login')
emailatyopamil.send_keys("janemartin90452")


P.press("enter")



driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[contains(text(), 'Activate Your Account')]/parent::button")).click()
# emailconfirmationatyopmail.click()

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath(...).click()`